# Upload files and Json to server using Flask framework

Tags: json, file-upload, flask

I am using Flask to design a dynamic form that send a json and files to the server with Ajax. For the Json part I succeed with this JQuery code:

```
$("#insert_recipe").submit(function(){
            $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "/_insert_recipe",
            contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data : JSON.stringify(recipe),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data, textStatus){
                window.location.replace("/");
                $("#insert_recipe").remove();
            }
```

However, Now I want to add files to the submit function, how to do that?
Thanks

Comment: Hi @nam. Not sure if this directly answers your question but file uploads should be handled in the normal way. [Uploading Files](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/fileuploads/) should explain how this is done. You just need to check the various ways to send a file with AJAX in jQUERY

Comment: Yes, so you mean it's not possible to add file data to json and to send the file and form all together to the server?

Comment: There are ways to do that. I think you can post a whole form with AJAX in jQuery but you will need to check the docs. There are definitely extensions to this. A quick Google search for 'AJAX file upload JQuery' brings up a lot of SO articles.

Comment: Yes I've tried uploadifive, jquery file upload, but It's file uploading, and I want to send both json doc and file at the same time.